# Route not being directed correctly

Tags: node.js, express

I have set up express to use the following paths:

```
const profile = require("./api/profile")
const events = require("./api/events")

app.use("/api/events", events)
app.use("/api/profile", profile)
```

Inside the events and profile `index.js` files I have the following:

```
const router = require('./../../modules/router.js')
router.get('/', (req, res) => {

})
module.exports = router
```

My router.js file:

```
const express = require("express")
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')()
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true})
const router = express.Router()
const firebase = require("./firebase.js")

// https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint
// Must have header 'Authorization: Bearer <Firebase ID Token>'
const validateFirebaseIdToken = (req, res, next) => {
  if ((!req.headers.authorization || !req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')) &&
      !req.cookies.__session) {
    res.status(403).send({ "error": 'Unauthorized'})
    return
  }

  let idToken
  if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
    // Read the ID Token from the Authorization header.
    idToken = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1]
  } else {
    // Read the ID Token from cookie.
    idToken = req.cookies.__session
  }
  firebase.admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken).then((decodedIdToken) => {
    req.user = decodedIdToken
    return next()
  }).catch(error => {
    res.status(403).send({"error": 'Unauthorized'})
  })
}
router.use(cors)
router.use(cookieParser)
router.use(validateFirebaseIdToken)

module.exports = router
```

For some reason, the router mixes up the paths `/api/events/` and `/api/profile/` whenever I call them. For all other paths it works fine. How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the same router for both events and profile, it could be the source of your issue.

Have you tested to create one router for each module?

Maybe try something like this for both events and profile:

```
const router = require('express').Router()
router.get('/', (req, res) => {

})
module.exports = router
```

Comment: I am using the same router, it's coming from a separate file router.js, where I initialise it. I haven't tested with separate ones

Comment: I edited my answer if you are willing to try what I propose. Also, can you share in your question what contains you router.js file?

Comment: Thank you! I've updated my question with the contents of `router.js`. It's a bit complex because of the router having to validate the requests.

Comment: Just tested, this is why it's not working! How can I make sure that all my routers use the `cors`, `cookieParser`, and `validateFirebaseToken` functions? The original reason I shared routers was because I don't want to repeat all that code in `router.js` in every file.

Comment: You can apply these middlewares directly to the app: app.use(cors())... and even apply application-level middleware for specific paths. See more on the doc : http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.application

Comment: Did not know that! Thank you, that worked, you've been super helpful.