# How to make all express routers use validation code

Tags: node.js, express

When I create a router I need to add the following code in each module:

```
const express = require("express")
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')()
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true})
const router = express.Router()
const firebase = require("./firebase.js")

// https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint
// Must have header 'Authorization: Bearer <Firebase ID Token>'
const validateFirebaseIdToken = (req, res, next) => {
  if ((!req.headers.authorization || !req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')) &&
      !req.cookies.__session) {
    res.status(403).send({ "error": 'Unauthorized'})
    return
  }

  let idToken
  if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
    // Read the ID Token from the Authorization header.
    idToken = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1]
  } else {
    // Read the ID Token from cookie.
    idToken = req.cookies.__session
  }
  firebase.admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken).then((decodedIdToken) => {
    req.user = decodedIdToken
    return next()
  }).catch(error => {
    res.status(403).send({"error": 'Unauthorized'})
  })
}
router.use(cors)
router.use(cookieParser)
router.use(validateFirebaseIdToken)

// api functions go here

module.exports = router
```

Initially I had this in a separate file and was sharing the router across modules, however, sharing caused problems. I don't want to copy and paste this code in each module file... How can I make sure that all routers are created like this with out having to copy and paste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to see exactly which part you want to share, but if you pull the `validateFirebaseIdToken` function into its own file, then you can import it like anything else. This is important because you can easily use it wherever you want. You may have routes which don't require authentication... in which case you wouldn't use this middleware.

**validate-firebase-token.js**

```
const firebase = require("./firebase.js")

const validateFirebaseIdToken = (req, res, next) => {
  if ((!req.headers.authorization || !req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')) &&
      !req.cookies.__session) {
    res.status(403).send({ "error": 'Unauthorized'})
    return
  }

  let idToken
  if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
    // Read the ID Token from the Authorization header.
    idToken = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1]
  } else {
    // Read the ID Token from cookie.
    idToken = req.cookies.__session
  }
  firebase.admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken).then((decodedIdToken) => {
    req.user = decodedIdToken
    return next()
  }).catch(error => {
    res.status(403).send({"error": 'Unauthorized'})
  })
}

module.exports = validateFirebaseIdToken
```

... and now your router code looks like this:

```
const express = require("express")
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')()
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true})
const router = express.Router()
const validateFirebaseIdToken = require('./validate-firebase-token')

router.use(cors)
router.use(cookieParser)
router.use(validateFirebaseIdToken)

// api functions go here

module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by someone in the answers to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50370322/route-not-being-directed-correctly), you can apply middleware on to the app rather than a specific router. That way the middleware applies to all requests!

Comment: I didn't fully read this answer before posting mine - but the problem with adding it to the whole app is that you might have sections of your app which do not require authentication. You can isolate the middleware as I showed you above and apply it to only the routes which require authentication.

Comment: @RyanWheale Thanks, that's a good point, accepted your answer :)